# Is there an epub reader that integrates well with elementary OS?

Tags: release-freya, applications

Looking for an e-reader app that integrates well with the elementary gtk+ theme, as other native apps do. Preferably with a nightmode feature also, and support for common formats. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm working in my free time to build a eBook reader for elementary OS - Bookworm.

Currently it's in a very early stage and very much work in progress. However, currently it can open eBooks and supports adding and removing books from the library. Here is the install instructions if you would like to try it. Suggestions and feature requests are more than welcome ...

https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/blob/master/README.md!

Answer (score 2):

Installed **Calibre** reader few days ago http://calibre-ebook.com/. Not bad. It's possible to customize it. For example, I use this theme http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=168291

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Is there a way to remove the titlebar, though?

Comment: There is a full screen mode like this http://imgur.com/CevJ5SB

Comment: Am I seeing the correct image? The falcon space agency thing :3 The full screen view might be bearable. I don't like those old gnome titlebars though. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, this image is a full screen mode screenshot. I tried to customize ui by changing icons as well, but didn't have enough time to discover is it possible to make general look of this application better.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

I only found one project that looks promising: [gnome-books](https://wiki.gnome.org/Outreach/SummerOfCode/2014/Projects/MartaMilakovic_GnomeBooks). Unfortunately, I could not get it working properly on Freya last time I tried.

Since the rest of the `.epub` readers currently available on Linux look dreadful, I usually use Calibre to convert my books to `.pdf` and use Evince (Document Viewer) to read them.

Comment: Yeah, I may do that. Gnome-books probably has a lot of gnome dependencies. Off-topic: Do your fonts render ok in Evince? The font hinting was a bit off or something last time I used it.